# Definitions of Group Cohomology

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

I am trying to understand group cohomology, and I have a very basic question. So as I understand it, let $\Gamma$ be a group, and $V$ be a $\Gamma$-module (which is essentially another abelian group acted on by $\Gamma$). We shall construct the group cohomology of $\Gamma$ with coefficients in $V$ by constructing a chain complex and taking its homology groups.

1) We could consider the "homogenous" version as follows: let
$$C^n(\Gamma,V)=\{f:\Gamma^{n+1} \to V\}$$
with a coboundary operator
$$d^n:C^n(\Gamma,V) \to C^{n+1}(\Gamma,V)$$
$$d^nf(g_0,g_1,\dots,g_{n+1})=\sum \limits_{i=0}^{n+1} (-1)^i f(g_0,\dots,\hat{g}_i,\dots,g_{n+1})$$
Now the chain
$$0 \to V \to C^1(\Gamma,V) \to C^2(\Gamma,V) \to \dots$$
is exact at every index, but we can consider the subspace of invariants under the action of $\Gamma$ on a function $f \in C^n(\Gamma,V)$ as follows
$$g\cdot f (g_0,\dots,g_n)=g\cdot f(g^{-1}g_0,\dots,g^{-1}g_n)$$
to get a complex
$$0 \to V^{\Gamma} \to C^1(\Gamma,V)^{\Gamma} \to C^2(\Gamma,V)^{\Gamma} \to \dots$$
and define $H^n(\Gamma,V)$ as the cohomology groups of this complex.

2) We can also define an "inhomogenous" complex to define the cohomology as follows: let
$$\tilde{C}^n(\Gamma,V)=\{f:\Gamma^{n} \to V\}$$
with a coboundary operator
$$\tilde{d}^n:C^n(\Gamma,V) \to C^{n+1}(\Gamma,V)$$
$$\tilde{d}^n f(g_1,\dots,g_{n+1})=g_1 \cdot f(g_2,\dots,g_{n+1}) + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^i f(g_1,\dots,g_ig_{i+1},\dots,g_{n+1}) + (-1)^{n+1} f(g_1,\dots,g_n)$$
The complex obtained
$$ V \to \tilde{C}^1(\Gamma,V) \to \tilde{C}^2(\Gamma,V) \to \dots$$
can be used directly to define the cohomology groups of $\Gamma$ in $V$ as the cohomology of this complex.

The equivalence of these two constructions can be seen by constructing isomorphisms between $C^n(\Gamma,V)^{\Gamma}$ and $\tilde{C}^{n+1}(\Gamma,V)$.

Note that in the first (homogenous) construction we explicitly specified an action of $\Gamma$ on functions in $f \in C^n(\Gamma,V)$ as follows
$$g\cdot f (g_0,\dots,g_n)=f(g^{-1}g_0,\dots,g^{-1}g_n)$$
and used invariants of that action to define the complex and cohomologies. This is in addition to the given action of $\Gamma$ on $V$ which is used to define $V^{\Gamma}$.

On the other hand, in the inhomogenous construction, we do not use any action of $\Gamma$ on functions, but only the given action of $\Gamma$ on $V$, which is just applied pointwise on function values.

So my question is:

> What happens if we use a different action of $\Gamma$ on functions in the homogenous construction? Or if we define our own action of $\Gamma$ on functions in the inhomogenous construction (not just using the action on $V$ pointwise)? Will the cohomologies change?

I really don't understand how the action of $\Gamma$ on functions fits together with the given action of $\Gamma$ on functions of $\Gamma^n$ into $V$. Apologies if this is elementary, but I'd be grateful for some explanation.

Comment: There's a variety of cohomology theories that can be defined, but I think the answer you're looking for is that "reasonably similar" constructions should give the same cohomology by abstract nonsense: namely, that a derived functor is independent of the choice of injective resolution (modulo some techincal requirements).

Comment: In the homogeneous cochain, the action of $\Gamma$ is not the one you described. This is rather $(g.f)(x_0,...,x_n)=gf(g^{-1}x_0,...,g^{-1}x_n)$. With this action of $\Gamma$, the group $C^n(\Gamma,V)^\Gamma$ is actually the group of equivariant maps $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}[\Gamma]}(\mathbb{Z}[\Gamma^{n+1}],V)$. So it does use the action of $\Gamma$ on $V$.

Comment: @Roland You're right, my mistake. I have corrected it now, thanks for pointing it out. But the broader question still stands. If we use a different action of $\Gamma$ on functions, say a conjugate action, then where would this break down? Is there any reason we define the action in that particular way?

Comment: Well, if you use a different action, it is a bit as if you changed the action on $V$. Look at the particular degree $n=0$. Then $H^0(\Gamma,V)$ is supposed to be $V^\Gamma$ for the action of $\Gamma$ on $V$. Now with the homogeneous cochain, $H^0(\Gamma,V)$ is the set of maps $\Gamma\to V$ such that $(g.f)=f$ and for all $g,h\in\Gamma, f(g)-f(h)=0$. So $f$ is constant and invariant, thus $H^0(\Gamma,V)=V^\Gamma$. If you use another action, then you won't get the expected result it may look as if you had chosen another action on $V$.

Comment: By the way, there is another mistake in the definition with the homogeneous cochain. You have a complex $0\to V\to C^0(\Gamma,V)\to C^1(\Gamma,V)\to...$ (including $n=0$) and you take the cohomology of $0\to C^0(\Gamma,V)^\Gamma\to C^1(\Gamma,V)^\Gamma\to ...$ (starting with $C^0$ and removing the $V^\Gamma$ part).

Comment: As long as you have the same underlying set, group structure and differentials on the chains, the $\Gamma$-structure does not matter. In general if you have modules over any ring $R$ you can calculate kernels, images and cokernels (i.e. quotients) by just considering the modules as abelian groups. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @Roland I had earlier acknowledged your comment that $(g\cdot f)(x_0,\dots,x_n)=gf(g^{-1}x_0,\dots,g^{-1}x_n)$. But now on further exploring, I find that in many places, they simply say $(g\cdot f)(x_0,\dots,x_n)=f(g^{-1}x_0,\dots,g^{-1}x_n)$ as I had earlier said. It also gels in betterwith the proof that amenable groups have trivial bounded cohomology. There the invariant mean uses the action $g\cdot f(x)=f(g^{-1}x)$ too. Are you sure which is correct?

Comment: What are your sources ? I am pretty sure that I am correct, and a reason for that is what you wrote in your first post : if you take only $(g.f)(x)=f(g^{-1}x)$, then this does not depend on the action of $\Gamma$ on $V$ which is obviously wrong. The different action gives different cohomology group.

Comment: @Roland I'll check again. Maybe in my references, they assume the trivial action of $\Gamma$ on $V$, in which case both the above expressions are equivalent. Which raises my other question: everywhere I see $H^n(\Gamma,V)$ as if it depends only on $\Gamma$ and $V$. Shouldn't it be $H^n(\Gamma,V,\rho)$ where $\rho$ is the given action of $\Gamma$ on $V$? Don't different actions give different cohomologies?

Comment: Well, $\rho$ is omitted because we should think of $V$ as not only an abelian group, but a representation. (You don't write $(V,+)$ even if the cohomology depends on the group structure on $V$...) I mean, the letter $V$ carries the set, the abelian group structure, the representation, the eventual structure of $R$-module... But yes, different actions give different cohomologies.